# finding peaks that have some structure in 1-d

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have signal with peaks that has some structure on top of some background, and I'm trying to find a robust way to locate their positions and amplitudes.

For example, assume the peak has this form:

```
t=linspace(0,10,1e3);
w=0.25;
rw=@(t0) 2/(sqrt(3*w)*pi^0.25)*(1-((t-t0)/w).^2).*exp(-(t-t0).^2/(2*w.^2));
```

and I have several peaks a bit too close so their structure starts to interfere with the others, and one separated, so you can see it's structure:

```
pos=[ 2 2.5 3 8]; % positions
total_signal=0.*t;
for i=1:length(pos) 
   total_signal=total_signal+rw(pos(i));
end
plot(t,total_signal);
```

[image: screenshot]

So the goal is to find all peaks found in `total_signal` and check that their positions agree with the original positions that were used to generate them in `pos`.

Comment: The question is not very clear. Which peak do you consider the one you want your algorithm to pin point to?

Comment: all of them, there are 4 peak positions, given in the `pos` vector.

Comment: [`findpeaks`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) already exists.

Comment: if I understand you correctly,  it will fail here in cases where peak amplitude change because it assumes no structure , just a local maxima. Here the peak has a particular function that generates it. more than just a local maxima. as a result when peaks are close the structure will start to mess up their maxima. as seen in the plot.

Comment: I'm wondering if this question would be more suited to the Digital Signal Processing stack overflow, https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You might want to look into deconvolution, if the peak shape is sufficiently similar always (doesn’t change width and so on) and known. Using deconvolution you can recover the pulse train that was convolved with the peak shape to produce your signal. `findpeaks` on the result would yield correct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your signal can be thought of as the convolution of a pulse train with the peak shape. Deconvolution can be used to retrieve the pulse train, whose peaks are the locations you are looking for. This assumes that the peak shape is known and constant.

I will start by rewriting your code as follows:

```matlab
t = linspace(0,10,1e3);
w = 0.25;
rw = @(t) 2/(sqrt(3*w)*pi^0.25)*(1-((t)/w).^2).*exp(-(t).^2/(2*w.^2));

pos = [2, 2.5, 3, 8];
total_signal = zeros(size(t));
for i=1:length(pos) 
   total_signal = total_signal + rw(t-pos(i));
end
total_signal = total_signal + randn(size(t))*1e-2;
plot(t,total_signal);
```

I've changed `rw` to take `t-t0`, rather than just `t0`. This will allow me later to create a clean signal with just one peak in the middle. I have also added noise to the signal, for a more realistic problem. Without the noise, the problem is a lot easier to solve.

[Wiener deconvolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_deconvolution) is the simplest approach to solve this problem. In short, we assume that

```
total_signal = conv(pulse_train, shape)
```

In the frequency domain, this is written as

```
G = F .* H
```

(with `.*` the element-wise multiplication, using MATLAB syntax here). The Wiener deconvolution is:

```
F = (conj(H) .* G) ./ (abs(H).^2 + k)
```

with `k` some constant that we can tune to regularize the solution.

We implement this as follows:

```matlab
shape = rw(linspace(-5,5,1e3));
G = fft(total_signal);
H = fft(ifftshift(shape)); % ifftshift moves the origin to sample #0, as expected by FFT.
k = 1;
F = (conj(H) .* G) ./ (abs(H).^2 + k);
pulse_train = ifft(F);
```

Now, `findpeaks` (requires the Signal Processing Toolbox) can be used to find the prominent peaks:

```matlab
findpeaks(pulse_train, 'MinPeakProminence', 0.02)
```

[image: output, showing 4 detected peaks at close to the same height]

Note how the four peaks are approximately the same height. It's not exact, because we're regularizing to deal with the noise. An exact solution is only possible in the noise-free case. Without noise, `k=0`, and the expression simplifies to `F = G ./ H`.

Also, the x-axis is off in the plot produced by `findpeaks`, but this shouldn't affect the results. The locations returned by it are indices into the array, those same indices can be used to index into `t` and find the actual locations of the peaks.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer! why do I get these "ripples" around the peaks? is there away to minimize them?

Comment: @dpdp: That's caused by the noise and the regularization. Play around with the `k` parameter, make it larger to reduce the ripples, but also reduce the peak quality.